# Translation Manager .NET API v2 - what's the new "SystemConfiguration"

Tags: translation-manager

The old Translation Manager API provided a *SystemConfiguration* class to provide read-only access to the Translation Manager configuration. This is now marked obsolete:

> Please use the classes and interfaces in the Tridion.TranslationManager.V1 namespace instead

I'm scanning through the new .NET API Tridion.TranslationManager.V2 documentation but can't seem to find the new alternative?

Has the capability to read the TranslationManager.xml been removed from the API or can I just not see for looking!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is true. New V2 API does not expose SystemConfiguration.

Can you please tell what exactly you are reading from configuration and how you use it. So we know how to improve TM API in future.

Comment: The ability to read the Smtp details from TranslationManager.xml file would be useful as part of some event system code I am writing.

Comment: Interesting, this sounds like part of some type of automatic email notification scenario based on actions in the Content Manager. I'm guessing it doesn't _need_ to be the SMTP server configured for Translation Manager, but it's useful to be able to connect to one that works?

Comment: Exactly. Whilst I'm able to roll my own config for my event code (and this may actually be better as the config is co-located with my DLL) I do have to redefine SMTP details I've already provided in the TM xml.